# USB mouse not working, unless unplug and plug it back

Tags: mouse

My new mouse isn't getting detected when I start my PC. I have to unplug & plug to make it work every time. My USB ports are fine and my earlier USB mouse still works fine. I have tried each of my USB ports, and they all exhibit the same problem. I removed-install driver from Device Manager, but no use. Any idea how to fix this?

Edit:

My PC: Dell Inspiron 3443 on Windows 10 and my mouse: Prolink Furax PMG9002

Comment: Does it happen only in one port?

Comment: @derloopkat it happens in every ports.

Comment: It might help if you told us the make and model of the mouse and the computer, and what operating system it is running.    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.